# How to place 100 different files on 20 file systems?

Tags: algorithm

I have `20` file systems of:

```
 /fs01
 /fs02
 /fs03
 ...
 /fs20
```

in my Unix environment. Each of these file systems, contains some free space, which I can use for saving files. These file systems are independent of each other, and each contain a different amount of free space.

I have `100` files of different sizes on another host and I want to place each of these files in any of the available locations. Obviously, after a file is placed on a specific file system, the amount of available free space on that particular file system will be reduced by the file size.

I am looking for an efficient way of doing this; i.e. an algorithm which gets the above data as input and give me a mapping like:

```
 /fs01    <- f1,f10,f29
 /fs02    <- f5,f30
 /fs03    <-nothing here. too small.
 ...
 /fs20    <- f89,f100
```

where `f1` is `file 1`, `f2` is `file 2`, etc.
Do you think if there is such an algorithm?

Comment: is `f100` is duplicated in the example ?

Comment: @zorksylar good point. Thanks. No it is not. I will correct it.

Comment: What criteria are you using for determining whether an allocation is "good?" Also, are you sufficiently space-constrained that all the files might not fit?

Comment: @templatetypedef Very good question, indeed! I would be happy if "all" the files are copied to the destination locations.

Comment: @templatetypedef Also, I cannot split the files: I either find an available spot and copy the file into it, or the whole file movement fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you can solve it using integer programming techniques.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

There are many free solvers out there.

The model is simple. You have 20x100 variables that can be 0 or 1. Every variable x_{i,j} means (0: file not in this file system, 1: file in this file system).
The constrain are:

- each variable is between 0 and 1 (being integers they are 0 or 1)
- the sum of all the variables related to a file is 1 (each file is in 1 file system only)
- the sum of all the variables related to a file system weighted by their size must be less than the free space.

Each point in the soluzione space is OK for you.

Comment: Sorry for the first version. I don't know why i switched to Italian in the middle

Comment: So, you believe this is an NP-hard problem?

Comment: In my opinion it is really similar to a Knapsack problem https://web.cs.ship.edu/~tbriggs/dynamic/ then remember that you need one solution not the best, solvers are optimized for that.

Comment: In which language do you want to implement it?

Comment: Java, C, Shell, whatever possible. Would it make a difference?

Comment: There are dozens of integer programming solvers out there. http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/ include one, configure it and check the performance. NP-hard problems are bad but solvable if are relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

At a very high level this is certainly one possibility. At a glance and ignoring sorting performance the main operation would run in quadratic time.

The goal here is to match the largest files to the file systems that have just enough space for them. This would not ensure that all files receive a placement.

```
files = [file1, file2, file3, ...]           # array of files
fs    = [fs1, fs2, fs3, ...]                 # array of file systems

files.sort()                                 # sort by size descending
fs.sort()                                    # sort by free space ascending

for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < fs.length; j++) {
    if (files[i].size <= fs[j].freespace) {  # if the filesystem has space for the file
      files[i].move(fs[j])                   # move the file to the filesystem
      fs[j].freespace -= files[i].size       # reduce free space by file size
    }
  }
}
```

This is because the crux of your problem is an optimization problem. The above would simply brute force a solution since it doesn't try to optimize file placement for maximum utilization of space.

In addition, the above would not work in all cases:

Working Case - FS1, FS4, FS6 : F5, F2, F1 (F5 -> FS6, F2 -> FS4, F1 -> FS1)

Fail Case    - FS6, FS8 : F5, F4, F3, F2  (F5 => FS6, F4 => FS8, F3 => FS8, F2 is orphaned)

On a larger scale your problem would benefit from the use of hueristics. One possibility is to use a genetic algorithm to generate distributions and chose the one with the highest fitness level.

You can read more about genetic algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)

A simple tutorial explaining how genetic algorithms can be used can be found [here](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat1.html)

Comment: 2 FS 6 and 4, 3 files 1 4 5. The solution exists but your algorithm doesn't find it. Am I right?

Comment: @B3rn475 

FS 2, 3, 4, 6 # Sorted ascending.
Files 5, 4, 1  # Sorted descending.

file 5 -> FS 6.
file 4 -> FS 4.
file 1 -> FS 6.

The algorithm would find a solution this way.

Comment: FS 6 - 8, Files 5 - 4 - 3 - 2. 5  => 6 | 4 => 8 | 3 => 8 | 2 no place to go. Real solution, 5 => 8 | 4 => 6 | 3 => 8 | 2 => 6